# How to enable Flash Player plugin in Safari on macOS?

Tags: macos, safari, adobe, adobe-flash

The issue is when I'm watching any video that uses flash player, it is showing abnormal behaviour.

Any ideas on how to check whether or not Safari is using Flash Player?

If not, then how to enable Flash Player plugin in Safari?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start by uninstalling Flash completely - very few web sites use it any more. If you don't have it you will see a clear indication if it's required.

Get the uninstaller from Adobe - [Uninstall Flash Player | Mac OS](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-mac-os.html)

**Warning:** Do not fall for any pop up telling you Flash is needed or out of date - they're scams, malware. If Flash is legitimately needed for a video, the placeholder for the video will say that Flash is required; usually quite simply, "plugin missing" or similar, possibly with a 'jigsaw puzzle piece' icon.
*It will not offer to go get it for you.*

If you ascertain Flash is actually required, make sure to fetch it directly from Adobe, don't click through any links you cannot see clearly.
https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Then to make sure it's enabled in Safari, go to Preferences > Websites. Scroll down the list on the left until you find Adobe Flash; select, then to the right, decide whether you want behaviour on, off or ask by default & for any specific sites.

Full instructions at Adobe: [Enable for Safari](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-safari.html)

Note that Flash is very nearly end-of-life & most browsers are going to start actively blocking it over the next year. If you're not certain whether you currently still need it, work without it.

Comment: In the `Preference -> Websites`, plugins are not showing. Is there any way to show plugins that are hidden ?

Comment: That would tell me you don't have any plugins. Mine doesn't have that either, but I **know** I don't have any. Test at Adobe https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/flash-player.html to see whether it is installed & active.

Comment: The test showed that flash player is not installed on my system.

Comment: Then your original premise is wrong & you are not watching Flash video… which is actually a good thing.

Comment: On Chrome (both Windows & Mac), the website is using flash player and Chrome is blocking the flash from running. I was reading somewhere that Chrome is removing Flash support from 2020. That could be the case I thought. So, I went for Safari. Then, I tried to browse the same website and tried to run any video and it was working fine. After sometime, the same thing started to happen on safari also.

Comment: If it works at all, it doesn't need Flash. It wouldn't start then stop if it did, it just wouldn't start at all. Is the link public, so we can test it?

Answer (score 1):

First, install FlashPlayer from the official site of [Adobe](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/).

[image]

Once you have the tool install,

1. Open **Safari**, and choose **Safari** > **Preferences**.
2. Click the **Websites** tab and scroll down to the Plug-ins section. Locate the Adobe Flash Player entry.
3. Click the checkbox to *enable Flash Player*.
4. Select a setting to use for Flash Player when you visit other websites.

   [image]
5. You can configure Flash for individual websites (domains). Select a website listed in this window, and choose to Ask, Off, or On.

**Note**: Site will appear once you try to browse it in Safari and then you can put Always ON as per your preferences.

[image]

Comment: In the `Preference -> Websites`, plugins are not showing. Is there any way to show plugins that are hidden ?

Comment: if you don't see the plugins, then I am sure you don't have Flash Player installed in your machine.  Have you installed it ? It will appear after you install it.

Comment: No, it's not installed.

Comment: Then, your video/link is not using any kind of Flash player as it is opening video.

Comment: Yup !! Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the video and see if it is behaving the same.
- Otherwise switch browsers at least. Safari doesn't support say [webm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) and there could be other formats too.
- If the website has really old infrastructure, still there is another alternative to Flash Player. Develop menu → User Agent. It helps me use some sites which require say internet explorer.
- Flash player, if supported in Catalina, would appear in Safari Preferences → Websites, in the sidebar. Also, you can see a separate entry for it in macOS Preferences.